# Proof Verification: $4x^2+6xy+4y^2>0$ unless both $x$ and $y$ are equal to $0$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, inequality, quadratic-forms

This is a problem from Spivak's Calculus 4th ed., Chapter 1, Problem 16(b).

> Using the fact that
>   $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = (x + y)^2 > 0$,
>   show that $4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2 >0$ unless $x$ and $y$ are both $0$.

This is my proof:

Firstly, as any non-zero number $a$ satisfies the inequality $a^2>0$ (I have proved that already), $(x+y)^2>0 \Rightarrow 3(x+y)^2$, $x^2>0$ and $y^2>0$

$\therefore 3(x+y)^2+x^2+y^2=4x^2+6xy+4y^2>0$

Does this make sense?

Comment: It makes lot of sense: it is even correct. Nice!

Comment: Cute. Most people would complete the square of $4x^2+6xy$ to obtain $4x^2+6xy+4y^2=(2x+3y/2)^2+7y^2/4,$ or would use the Quadratic Formula to show that  $4x^2+6xy+4y^2=0$ implies both $x= (-6y\pm \sqrt {-28y^2})/8$ and $y=(-6x\pm \sqrt {-28x^2})/8.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost correct. The only flaw lies in the fact that you should assume only that $x\neq0$ *or* $y\neq0$. Therefore, you cannot say that both numbers $x^2$ and $y^2$ are greater than $0$. But you *can* say that their *sum* is greater than $0$, and that is quite enough for the proof.

Comment: That really confused me, so maybe I missed something: if $\;x,y\neq0\;$ then *by all means* $\;x^2,\,y^2>0\;$ ...! Of course, I assume all the way $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: What the OP was trying to prove was that if $x\neq0$ **or** $y\neq0$, then $4x^2+6xy+4^2>0$. But **one** of the numbers $x$ and $y$ *can* be equal to $0$.

Comment: Carlos Where did you deduce that "or" from the OP?

Comment: From “unless $x$ and $y$ are both $0$”. The opposite of this consists in asserting that $x\neq0$ or $y\neq0$.

Comment: One of them can indeed be equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
since

$\begin{array}\\
ax^2+2bxy+ay^2
&=a(x^2+y^2)+b(x^2+2xy+y^2)-b(x^2+y^2)\\
&=(a-b)(x^2+y^2)+b(x+y)^2\\
\end{array}
$

if
$a > b$ then
$ax^2+2bxy+ay^2 \ge 0$
with equality if and only if
$x = y = 0$.

Your case is
$a=4, b=3$.

You can handle the more general case of
$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$
by looking at how
the quadratic formula
is derived.